# Selenium clicking loop ignored some values

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automated-tests

I'm trying to run the code:

```
for j in range(1,13):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gateway-page"]/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[2]/ul/li['+str(j)+']').click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

To click every satisfying element on this [website](http://website(http://catalog.sps.cuny.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=2&poid=607)). But it ignores some elements every time, while it worked when I tried them not in the for loop but separately. Any idea why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems problem is with `/ul/li['+str(j)+']` you are performing the click on `<li>` tag while actual link reside in it. That's why sometime the actual link won't receive the click without any error as link wrapped inside `<li>` tag .

Try to locate actual link tag. Use below code. I have tested on my system. Hope this will help you.

```
driver.get('http://catalog.sps.cuny.edu/preview_program.php?catoid=2&poid=607')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//h2[contains(.,'Electives')]/..//ul/li//span/a")

for link in links:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

After observing xpath, I observed that you are trying to click the `Elective` option on that website. I think you have stored text of all electives in `str` array and using the loop, you are trying to click on each elective.

I suggest using another approach. Store all electives in list and then iterate over the elements and click them. e.g.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('///*[@id="gateway-page"]/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[2]/ul/li')
for element in elements:
    element.click()
    time.sleep()
```

Probable problems in your solution

1. You are storing the name of electives in the array. If there is any typo, xPath will become invalid
2. You are starting loop from 1 to 13 but str is 0 indexed so start the loop from 0. because in you case you will always miss the first elective
3. Also after each click, elective expands. So you can also think about scrolling if an element is not found

Suggestion:

Also, use relative xpaths instead of absolute. Relative xpaths are more stable.

Happy Coding~